# php query search erratic results

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to create a search bar to query my MySql Db.

```
<?php
$query = $_POST['search_name']; 

$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$query);
    $raw_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `companies`
        WHERE (`name` LIKE '%$query%')");

    if(mysqli_fetch_row($raw_results) > 0){ 
        while($results = mysqli_fetch_row($raw_results)){

            echo "<p>".$results[0]." ".$results[1]."</p>";

        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Now, If I type in the bar *gaio*, I don't get the result `Gaiotto Automation`. Surprisingly if I type the query directly in the SQL terminal

```
 SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%gaio%')
```

then the result is `Gaiotto Automation`, that is what I want. If I type in the search bar `autom` then I get `Gaiotto Automation` amongst the results.

Comment: You're doing `mysqli_fetch_row()` twice. I think you want the first one `mysqli_num_rows()` instead.

Comment: Oh Boyz! Sorry Everybody, Thanks @Mr.Blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful using php var in your sql code you are at risk for sqlinjection

for avoid this you should check for your db driver for binding param

Anyway You should build the query strung patter in a proper way  eg: uisng concat

```
  $raw_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `companies`
        WHERE (`name` LIKE concat('%', '$query', '%') )");
```

Comment: I think the bit about sql injection should come at the top. There shouldn't be a bottom.

Comment: @Strawberry  as you suggested

Comment: Well, half as I suggested ;-)

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge you mean that $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$query); is not enough to sanitize the sql? What would you suggest?

Comment: i suggest you the use of prepare  with param , binding param and execute  ..  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your parameter is not trimmed, but in any case I suggest that you use prepared statements

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

You know that your sql syntax works directly so you can debug by echoing the sql statement on the post page.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysqli_fetch_row` in `if condition` as it already extracted the results in if condition so it won't work next time.

```
<?php
$query = $_POST['search_name']; 

$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$query);
    $raw_results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%$query%')");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
        while($results = mysqli_fetch_row($raw_results)){

            echo "<p>".$results[0]." ".$results[1]."</p>";

        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're even vaguely concerned about security, do not do this.

Comment: @Strawberry please explain your concern